# Logging with MS Enterprise Library

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, app-config

I am using MS Enterprise Library version 4.1 in my class library. In the app.config file i have inserted appropriate entries for "loggingConfiguration" and "exceptionHandling" in the config file. But, it gives a crash i.e. "The configuration section for Logging cannot be found in the configuration source."

**configSections**

```
<configSections> 
    <section name="loggingConfiguration"
             type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSetting‌​s, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, 
                   Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" /> 
    <section name="exceptionHandling" 
             type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.Exce‌​ptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, 
                   Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Answer (score 2):

as the error says, you will need to link them in your configSection as well (just entering loggingConfiguration and exceptionHandling nodes won't do).

[This MSDN pages has some Hands on Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx) which I found quite useful

Comment: I have already made that linking in configSection.i.e.<configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>

Comment: To elaborate more, I am doing the logging in a (WCF RIA Service's web class library) and this project's reference is used in the web project.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error message. My problem was that I was referencing two different versions of Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.

I was referencing 4.1.0.0 but the config file Version was pointing to 5.0.414.0. Also had mixed up versions of the library in the project.